# Best Practice for Setting state on Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm learning `react-router-dom` and I created a big menu.

If a `Route` is active, I want to set the state accordingly. Currently I did something like

```
<Route
  path={url}
>
  <StateOnRouteChange
    {...props}
  />
</Route>
```

Where in `StateOnRouteChange` I set the state using the useEffect Hook on Mount. Seems hacky, but it works.
The problem here is, that it slows down the rendering significantly. So what is the proper way to set the state on a route?

Comment: Where is `props` defined? And, what exactly does `StateOnRouteChange` do or render?

Comment: `props` is the data I need to change the state. `StateOnRouteChange` is a component which returns null, but has a `useEffect` Hook that modifies the context.